# Problem with using subscriber from initialize method

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I am porting my project from Noetic to Foxy and I have flowing code:

```
bool STMRobotHW::initialize(ros::NodeHandle nh)
{
   ...
   hw_feedback_sub = nh.subscribe("hw_feedback", 1000, &STMRobotHW::feedbackCallback, this);
}

void STMRobotHW::feedbackCallback(const minicar_control::Feedback &fb_msg)
{
     ....
}
```

I have hard time understanding how this subscribe should look in Foxy if there are no obj parameter parameter for create_subscribe in ROS 2, or at least I couldn't find any. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408262/problem-with-using-subscriber-from-initialize-method./) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-20**:
Please look at [Writing a simple publisher and subscriber (C++)](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html)  tutorial suggested by @thejeeb. Furthermore, you can look at [ros2/examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/foxy) and [ros2/demos](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/foxy)

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-21**:
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a Node to create a subscriber. See [this](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) tutorial for an example.

---

Originally posted by [thejeeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/54884/thejeeb/) with karma: 118 on 2022-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-21**:
Thank you, for your help. I'll try it